# how do I get pycurl to send cookies but not save them to file?

Tags: python, cookies, pycurl

I need pycurl to save cookies from a posted form and then use those cookies in the next URL which is in the same domain. It doesn't seem to do this automatically.

Ive read the COOKIEFILE and COOKIEJAR options but I dont want to save these cookies to file. So is there some other way of enabling cookies with curl/pycurl without saving them to file?

Answer (score 5):

Well the libcurl docs states that:

> **CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE**
>
> Given an empty or non-existing file or by passing the empty string (""), this option will enable cookies for this curl handle, making it understand and parse received cookies and then use matching cookies in future requests.

Just tried it myself and it works brilliantly, just use the same curl object.

**Example**

```
import pycurl
curl = pycurl.Curl()

# Turn on cookies
curl.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEFILE, "")

# Login
curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, "http://www.example.com/login.php")
curl.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
curl.setopt(pycurl.HTTPPOST, [('user', 'myuser'), ('pass', 'mypass'), ('submit', 'login')])
curl.perform()

# Now let's get us some members only page
curl.setopt(pycurl.POST, 0) 
curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, "http://www.example.com/members_only.php")
curl.perform()
```

I skipped the whole StringIO response getting so we could stay ontopic.

Answer (score 1):

According to the PycURL site, the real documentation is the C API. The C API CURLOPT_COOKIE and CURLOPT_COOKIELIST that on a cursory glace [look like what you need](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html).

Comment: CURLOPT_COOKIELIST docs show how to set cookies for a request, but it if you're logging in and the web server wants to save cookies, it'd not clear how will you get back an updated list of cookies.

Comment: If you want to read the cookie name from the web server and don't want to use CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE or CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, you'll probably have to read the Set-Cookie response header manually. Were I you I'd figure out how to make cookiefile or cookiejar practicable.